# Cpputest: how to compile and use expectNoCall?

Tags: testing, mocking, cpputest

I have wrote the syntax: `mock().expectNoCall("productionCode")` as Cpputest.org page says. But the compiler says *that mocksupport class doesn't support this type of order.*

```
test_RFID_Drv.c:322:9: error: ‘class MockSupport’ has no member named ‘expectNoCall’mock().expectNoCall("HAL_AS393x_ReadRegisters");
```

How can it be used? Must I include some file at headers?
Currently I have those ones for mocking:

```
/*! \include <CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h> */
#include <CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h>
/*! \include <CppUTest/TestHarness.h> */
#include <CppUTest/TestHarness.h> 
/*! \include <CppUTestExt/MockSupport.h> */
#include <CppUTestExt/MockSupport.h>
```

The thing is that I want to ignore one concret system call. I don't want to test it.

Comment: Where are you reading the docs? I can see `mock().expectNCalls(5, "productionCode");` and ``mock().ignoreOtherCalls();` but not `expectNoCall`.

Comment: https://cpputest.github.io/mocking_manual.html in last Last paragraph. With the tittle: "Miscellaneous" and then, under a little explanation  (one line or two aprox).

Comment: Maybe expectNoCall is not done for this. But I would like to ignore one call  placed between other ones that I want to call under the same case test. If I use ignoreothercalls I have not clear if the rest of the calls, following this, will be called. I need the rest, after ignored call, will be called. Or at least, to find the way of stopping ignoreothercalls effect before the end ot the test case.

Comment: Can you provide a small example that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I have created another thread question separate from this question because they are two different questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301539/cpputest-how-to-ignore-only-one-call-placed-between-other-ones

Comment: I too would like to use expectNoCall, but it's not present in the version I've just downloaded. I'm testing C++.

Answer (score 1):

Eugenia, You are in a '.c' file, `mock().expectXX` is a syntax for '.cpp' files.

[This](https://github.com/felipe-lavratti/reacto/blob/e1c091542994e182007f588027d66a31e4acabd2/reacto_tests/src_tests/reusables/test_signal_slot.cpp#L51) is a working example of no expectations in a .cpp file.

If you need to use mock from .c files, include "MockSupport_c.h" and make sure you use the correct c syntax, read the header [here](https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest/blob/master/include/CppUTestExt/MockSupport_c.h).

If you don't want to use the syntax of the "_c" header, make your mocks file a .cpp and add the `export "C"` linker modifier to your mocked function, such as I did [here](https://github.com/felipe-lavratti/reacto/blob/ad3f37eb503049cf76c9c98bdec32e590438b17e/reacto_tests/src_tests/watchdog/hardware_watchdog.cpp).

Comment: My test file is .c and the only instruction it doesn't like was expectNocall. The rest of mock().X works propperly.