# CPPUTEST: How to ignore only one mocked call placed between other ones

Tags: testing, mocking, embedded, cpputest

I would like to ignore one call placed between other ones that I want to call under the same case test. If I use ignoreothercalls I have not clear if the rest of the calls, following this, will be called. I need the rest, after ignored call, will be called. Or at least, to find the way of stopping ignoreothercalls effect before the end of the test case.

```
TEST(group, test1){

    ...
    mock().expectOneCall("HAL_AS393x_CommandStrobes").withParameter("cCommandCode",AS393X_CMD_CALIB_RCO_LC);    
    /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
    mock().expectOneCall("HAL_AS393x_ReadRegisters");//I want ignore only this mocked function call
    /*-------------------------------------------------*/
    mock().expectOneCall("HAL_AS393x_Deinit");
    ...

}
```

I would like to leave this call without being tested, and remove it from de test case without gettig expecting calls errors for it: 
     mock().**xxxCall**("HAL_AS393x_ReadRegisters"); //-where **xxxCall** = unkown keyword used for this-

Comment: That is not C .

Answer (score 1):

You have to check expectation in between:

```
mock().expect...
do_something_that_call_mocks();
mock().checkExpectations();

/* Start all over again */
```

Complete example using checkExpectations() to reset mock() [here](https://github.com/felipe-lavratti/reacto/blob/88b454fa28c206627214e6720f7133eed0ebcf72/reacto_tests/src_tests/test_timed_queue.cpp#L185)

Comment: Hi Eugenia, did it help?

Comment: Hello Felipe, sorry I was occuped and I could not try this option yet. If I understood well, are you telling me I can ignore one mocked call by writing mock().checkExpectations(); after it? What do you mean with start all over againg? The idea is not to evaluate a concret mocked call in a test case. You know, if I comment or suppess the code line from the test, there will be a console error message. Sorry if I'm so new on this. So I don't know if cpputest has some way to do it.